# Should We Really Be Using Titlecase in Question Titles?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I don't particularly like using title case in questions but I guess this could be rather nit picky of me. It is reserved for titles of articles, chapters that sort of thing.

I wanted to edit the title of this post

[What is the recommended way to mortise melamine particleboard?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/mortising-melamine-particle-board/3150#3150)

At the time is was "Mortising Melamine Particle Board". I was temped to edit it to more proper case for a sentence to "Mortising melamine particle board" or even "Suggestions for mortising melamine particle board". The latter was appealing since the OP was not sure about what tools to use even.

Would there ever be a time that title case would be appropriate or does it really not matter. I would like if the questions looked consistent.

Comment: Are you asking about grammar here, like genitive case, dative case, nominative case, title case? Or are you referring to something like upper-case, lower-case, title-case?

Answer (score 4):

I think question titles should be formatted as proper questions--e.g., what is the recommended way to mortise melamine particle board?

Comment: Thanks for the input